# How to deselect a row from List(Julia)?

Tags: julia, gtk

How can I remove the selection from the already selected and processed row in the list displayed in the window?

```
ls = GtkListStore(String, Int, Bool)
push!(ls,("Peter",20,false))
push!(ls,("Paul",30,false))
push!(ls,("Mary",25,true))
tv = GtkTreeView(GtkTreeModel(ls))
rTxt = GtkCellRendererText()
rTog = GtkCellRendererToggle()
c1 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Name", rTxt, Dict([("text",0)]))
c2 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Age", rTxt, Dict([("text",1)]))
c3 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Female", rTog, Dict([("active",2)]))
push!(tv, c1, c2, c3)
win = GtkWindow(tv, "List View")
showall(win)
selection = GAccessor.selection(tv)
signal_connect(selection, "changed") do widget
  if hasselection(selection)
    currentIt = selected(selection)
    println("Name: ", ls[currentIt,1], " Age: ", ls[currentIt,1])
  end
end
```

For example I have this code, and I want to disable the activation of a row after it'll show the window and print "Name: ", ls[currentIt,1], " Age: ", ls[currentIt,1].
Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I don’t think there’s enough context here to answer your question. What window? What kind of list? What are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an `unselect!` function that Gtk.jl exports for this. However, directly calling it from within the `signal_connect`'s `do` block leads to a Segmentation fault.

As the last part of this [Gtk.jl manual page](http://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/signals/) recommends, changing the call to be an `@async` call or using `Gtk.GLib.@sigatom` on it avoids the segfault:

```
if hasselection(selection)
  currentIt = selected(selection)
  @async unselect!(selection, currentIt)
  println("Name: ", ls[currentIt,1], " Age: ", ls[currentIt,1])
end
```